# Deleted emails in my S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

My S4 is showing that there are 97 emails in my deleted folder but I can't see them. I deleted about 100 others at the same time, but these say they are still in the folder.

Comment: What email app are you using? Can you see those emails on a web or desktop interface?